# How to change float type to Postgresql MONEY type in sqlalchemy. It says MONEY cannot compare with float

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

How to change float type to Postgresql MONEY type in sqlalchemy. It says MONEY cannot compare with float in a query.
I need a type change when query

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: Read this [Money](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html) for casting rules. Though as @a_horse_with_no_name commented it a good idea to not use the `money` type.